# Obtaining the "user.dir" system property for a java process from the command line

Tags: java, command-line, process, system-properties

I am trying to read the system property "user.dir" from the command line for a particular java process. I have seen several examples of obtaining the system property from Java code (System.getProperty), however I need the system property set for another java process.

How can I obtain the same?

Comment: You can set the system property via command line parameter: `-Duser.dir=foo`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The only way to know is to have the other process tell you ... or otherwise poke about and try to see how it was setup ... perhaps with a debugger attached ...

Comment: The 'java process' - is it being launched as a [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) from within your code?

Comment: The java process is a third party java process - such as tomcat. I can either use a command-line/ a java program to obtain the system properties of the third party java process

Answer (score 1):

To get system property you can use `System.getProperty()`

```
System.out.println("User Home Path: "+System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

To set System property you can use `System.setProperty()`

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", "E:\\Eclipse Indigo workspace");
```

Comment: You should never set user.dir to a different value, as there are places throughout Java that expect this to be the same as the actual working directory!

Answer (score 0):

See below link with below excerpt:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

*The setProperties method changes the set of system properties for the current running application.* These changes are not persistent. That is, changing the system properties within an application will not affect future invocations of the Java interpreter for this or any other application. The runtime system re-initializes the system properties each time its starts up. **If changes to system properties are to be persistent, then the application must write the values to some file before exiting and read them in again upon startup.**

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answers, Sunil and Garry.. Maybe my question was a little unclear..I wish to know the system properties set by a third party java process such as tomcat. If I can get the process Id of the third party java process, is there any way to get its system properties from the command line/a different java application? 

Thanks again!